# PromQL Joining / Grouping by labels where multiple labels are present

Tags: grafana, promql

The metrics I get are in the form:

```
{name="name1", count="1"}
{name="name2", count="2"}
{name="name1", count="3"}
{name="name3", count="2"}
{name="name3", count="1"}
{name="name3", count="2"}
{name="name2", count="4"}
{name="name1", count="0"}
```

I want to form a time graph showing change in `count` for different `name` values.

Example:

`name1` should have a line depicting changes 1 -> 3 -> 0

`name2` should have a line depicting changes 2 -> 4

`name3` should have a line depicting changes 2 -> 1 -> 2

I tried `sum by (name, count)` but it created a new curve for each different `count` of the `name`

Please suggest me a way to accomplish my task.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like misuse on labels. Hint: if you intend to use label value as value for graphing - you doing it wrong. Convert your metric, so that what is currently a count label would be an actual metrics value.